# Gitolite create repository with gitolite user locally

Tags: git, ssh, local, gitolite

I want to create a new repository on my gitolite server with the local account, without accessing through SSH. Is this possible? Are they some gitolite scripts that i can use?

If I try to configure gitolite via the git user on my system by checking out the `gitolite-admin` repo and configuring it accordingly. But i can't push my changes because the hooks will crash, since i'm not logged in via SSH.

Why do I want to do that? I want to setup gitolite via Chef and create a new repo. But i don't want to provide the private key to the Chef scripts.

### Edit

For everyone whos trying to use also chef for setting up gitolite. There is a [bug](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-2288) which prohibits naive usage of the bash resource, so you have to specify some environment data explicitly, since gitolite uses them:

```
bash "gitolite push" do
  cwd "/home/git/gitolite-admin"
  user "git"
  group "git"
  environment ({ 'HOME' => ::Dir.home('git'), 'USER' => 'git' })
  code "../bin/gitolite push"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on the gitolite server, one easy solution is to:

- clone the bare admin repo directly

  ```
  cd ~
  git clone repositories/gitolite-admin.git
  cd gitolite-admin/conf
  // Declare a new repo in gitolite.conf
  git add
  git commit -m "New repo"
   ~/bin/gitolite push
  ```

The [`gitolite push` is documented here](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/emergencies.html#ce).

> If you really must do it, and this is a one-time thing, you can try `gitolite push` instead of `git push`.
>   BUT... this defeats all gitolite access control, so if you're going to do this often, maybe you don't need gitolite!

Comment: i get errors on `git push`:                                   
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 335 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Empty compile time value given to use lib at hooks/update 
remote: Can't locate Gitolite/Hooks/Update.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Gitolite::Hooks::Update module)
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
To /home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to '/home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git'

Comment: @atx what error? Are you on the gitolite server itself? What does a `git remote -v` shows you, when executed from the local clone?

Comment: yes i'm on the gitolite server itself. I operate with the gitolite user, but also have root access.

Comment: git remote -v
    origin /home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git (fetch)
    origin /home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git (push)

Comment: okay i'm getting closer! i had to do the following in order to fetch the repo: `cd repositories/gitolite-admin; git remote add origin ../../gitolite-admin; git fetch origin master:master` if i just did the `git fetch ..` it wouldnt be merged into the bare repo.

Comment: @atx ok, I have included those commands in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: but even after running `./bin/gitolite setup` gitolite didn't created a new repo. i think its because the `.gitolite/conf/gitolite.conf` doesn't get updated, since the hooks are not fired. any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60064/discussion-between-atx-and-vonc).

Comment: @atx Ihave updated the answer with the `gitolite push` command documentation.